# Unsafe return of an `any` typed value.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm using Vue and typescript in my project and I'm having problems returning a function when trying to validate my form.
Here's the errors:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ name: ((v: string) => string | true)[]; enrollment: ((v?: string) => Fn)[]; cpf: ((number: string) => string | true)[]; profession: ((v: unknown) => Fn)[]; admission_date: ((v: unknown) => Fn)[]; department: ((v: unknown) => Fn)[]; email: ((v: unknown) => Fn)[]; phone: ((v: unknown) => Fn)[]; }'.   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ name: ((v: string) => string | true)[]; enrollment: ((v?: string) => Fn)[]; cpf: ((number: string) => string | true)[]; profession: ((v: unknown)
=> Fn)[]; admission_date: ((v: unknown) => Fn)[]; department: ((v: unknown) => Fn)[]; email: ((v: unknown) => Fn)[]; phone: ((v: unknown)
=> Fn)[]; }'.
```

And

```
Unsafe return of an `any` typed value.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return
```

My code:

```
const myRules = {
  name: [
    isPersonName('', t),
  ],      
  enrollment: [
    eqLength('', 4, t)
  ],    
  cpf: [
    isValidCpf(t),
  ],
  profession: [isRequired('', t)],
  admission_date: [isRequired('', t)],
  department: [isRequired('', t)],
  email: [isRequired('', t)],
  phone: [isRequired('', t)],      
}
```

Here is exactly where my error happens:

```
//@ts-ignore
const getMyRules = (item: string) => myRules[item]
```

What I can't understand is that if I run the console my data is displayed correctly inside my console, but when I try to return this value ESlint gives me the error.

```
    //@ts-ignore
    const getMyRules = (item: string) => console.log(fieldRules[item])
```

My inputs:

```
<component
  v-for="field in getFields()"
  v-bind="field.props"
  :mask="addMaskInputs(field.name)"
  :rules="getMyRules(field.name)"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the code you posted there is no type definitions given for `myRules`, it may be that typescript cannot infer the result of getting something from that object. What may help is if you hint that the `item` parameter is of type `keyof myRules`:

```
const myRules = {/* ... */};
const getMyRules = (item: keyof myRules) => myRules[item];
```

Note also that I left off `| undefined` from the 'item' parameter, because if you are allowed to pass undefined then typescript will take `getMyRules` to possibly return `myRules[undefined]` (which probably is `undefined` or a runtime error).

If it may be the case that you are calling `getMyRules` with a variable that may or may not be undefined, then you should fix the types over there first. Your type system will unravel at the loosest definitions first.

Comment: @user19015424user Hi, thanks for replying. I performed some tests using 'keyof', but without success. Even defining a type the error remained

Comment: What is the error message when you specify it as keyof?
It may be the case that when you specify the argument as keyof that you get a different error at the place where you call the function.